# Plot time-series data in POSIXct form as boxplots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I have time series data of three months as:

```
structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1438367400, 1438453800, 
1438540200, 1438626600, 1438713000, 1438799400, 1438885800, 1438972200, 
1439058600, 1439145000, 1439231400, 1439317800, 1439404200, 1439490600, 
1439577000, 1439663400, 1439749800, 1439836200, 1439922600, 1440009000, 
1440095400, 1440181800, 1440268200, 1440354600, 1440441000, 1440527400, 
1440613800, 1440700200, 1440786600, 1440873000, 1440959400, 1441045800, 
1441132200, 1441218600, 1441305000, 1441391400, 1441477800, 1441564200, 
1441650600, 1441737000, 1441823400, 1441909800, 1441996200, 1442082600, 
1442169000, 1442255400, 1442341800, 1442428200, 1442514600, 1442601000, 
1442687400, 1442773800, 1442860200, 1442946600, 1443033000, 1443119400, 
1443205800, 1443292200, 1443378600, 1443465000, 1443551400, 1443637800, 
1443724200, 1443810600, 1443897000, 1443983400, 1444069800, 1444156200, 
1444242600, 1444329000, 1444415400, 1444501800, 1444588200, 1444674600, 
1444761000, 1444847400, 1444933800, 1445020200, 1445106600, 1445193000, 
1445279400, 1445365800, 1445452200, 1445538600, 1445625000, 1445711400, 
1445797800, 1445884200, 1445970600, 1446057000, 1446143400, 1446229800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Asia/Kolkata"), power = c(0.0247230720457733, 
0.0108825766825672, 0.0288152903005685, -0.0234123772463031, 
-0.00919754217224866, -0.0374403275019726, -0.0078777961550861, 
0.0079837844138577, 0.00575982953501377, 0.0202857581215497, 
0.0258757511850728, -0.0337682832455853, 0.0341912141620086, 
-0.0042798060711745, 0.00675858841374106, -0.00246125938541154, 
0.00912344869950909, 0.0206439842553702, -0.01940932272705, -0.0100830115181366, 
-0.00734857221326485, -0.0170222915573808, 0.0285240366773044, 
0.00764357383266427, -0.0238453527011212, -0.00672944465931788, 
0.00818204423502334, 0.00460125531472914, 0.0230428947908782, 
0.00154030144193071, 0.0189660255911821, 0.0155756949832998, 
0.0267515034089843, 0.0214963580786819, 0.0029481279523321, 0.00986682946599846, 
0.00832138782007834, -0.00676599971272203, -0.00324283490587677, 
0.0204023688477303, 0.0229717200642572, 0.0251381446922004, 0.00584010113018711, 
-0.00465215879879816, -0.0308844467014504, 0.000780093550060347, 
0.00369764046959574, -0.0160883189684658, 0.0218083597791737, 
-0.021605117962637, 0.000445192082904827, -0.00372433762871899, 
0.0106455591452724, 0.024611532476291, 0.0132632680432167, 0.0149559186037772, 
-0.0453599092776512, -0.0202099060937128, 0.0169712680315599, 
0.0148844950106621, -0.0391221225281138, 0.00461340547288957, 
0.0118982098114901, -0.00571305945781934, 0.0143190640584365, 
-0.0117202800880833, 0.0394635775820876, -0.00393737330560111, 
0.00633578511802405, 0.0402779799675971, -0.00146576620678839, 
-0.00974562394885507, 0.0179401329290733, -0.0157766103469759, 
0.00534190906349559, 0.0021055773020779, -0.018236876969857, 
-0.00392926841238278, -0.0065097462318096, -0.0249870099671041, 
-0.0139735459289521, 0.000625022444854668, -0.00278827413472659, 
0.0179048032598685, -0.0268735489312987, -0.00760559474288195, 
0.0179536496832603, -0.0126341858034209, -0.0338553507687797, 
-0.0045297254037134, -0.0106755306681489, -0.0154881466662607
)), .Names = c("timestamp", "power"), row.names = c(NA, -92L), class = "data.frame")
```

The structure of given data frame is:

```
> str(h2)
'data.frame':   92 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ timestamp: POSIXct, format: "2015-08-01" "2015-08-02" "2015-08-03" "2015-08-04" ...
 $ power    : num  0.0247 0.0109 0.0288 -0.0234 -0.0092 ...
```

Now, I want to plot this data in the form of boxplots using ggplot2. I believe there will be *three boxes with whisker*s corresponding to three months. Till now, I am using following code for this:

```
ggplot(dats) +geom_boxplot(aes(x=timestamp,y=power,group=timestamp),width = 0.5) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) +
   scale_x_datetime(labels = date_format("%b "), breaks="1 month")
```

I believe that I am not able to group the data properly by month. If I am correct, how should I group the data in monthly form so that boxplots will be drawn?

Note: I have provided one answer for this problem, but in the answer I convert timestamp from POSIXct to factor. However, I want to plot using given POSIXct timestamp, because conversion process consumes some extra time.

Comment: assuming timestamp is already converted to date-time, try loading the lubridate package and converting timestamp to month with the month function. this will covert the timestamp to months and your code should work from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note: Dataset used in this answer is entirely different than the one specified in question

On conversion of POSIXct form to factor, following script can be used:

```
    #First convert timestamp to months format and use levels so that final output 
    #is presented in chronological order and not in alphabetical order
    dats$timestamp <- factor(strftime(dats$timestamp,"%b"),levels = month.abb)
    ggplot(dats) +geom_boxplot(aes(x=timestamp,y=power))    +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + xlab("Time Period") +ylab("Power")
```

The final plot is:
[image]
**UPDATE**
Without time conversion,i.e., directly based on POSIXct timestamps,I did it as

```
ggplot(dats) +geom_boxplot(aes(x=timestamp,y=power, group=months(timestamp)))+
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90,hjust=1)) + xlab("Time Period") +ylab("Power") +
    scale_x_datetime(breaks="1 month", labels = date_format("%b"))
```

I want the same type of plot using POSIXct form.